# Override/extend static properties on ES7 classes in React.js

Tags: javascript, inheritance, static, reactjs, ecmascript-2016

ES7 introduces the concept of `static` property and method definitions. Along with an ES7-capable transpiler, these [can be used in React](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus/#property-initializers) to specify validators and defaults for `props`, like so:

```
export default class ComponentOne extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        foo: React.PropTypes.string
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        foo: 'bar'
    }
    // ...
}
```

This is super handy, but gets tricky when subclasses come into play. For example, say the following module is added to the same codebase as `ComponentOne` above:

```
export default class ComponentTwo extends ComponentOne {
    static propTypes = {
        baz: React.PropTypes.number
    }
    static defaultProps = {
        baz: 42
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'd like `ComponentTwo` to "inherit" the property validators and defaults of its superclass, `ComponentOne`. Instead, `propTypes` and `defaultProps` on `ComponentTwo` shadow those on `ComponentOne`, and React tosses out those defined on `ComponentOne`.

Since `super` is a reference to the current class's prototype, and `static` is supposed to reference values hung directly off the prototype, I thought this might work:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
export default class ComponentTwo extends ComponentOne {
    static propTypes = _.merge(super.propTypes, {
        baz: React.PropTypes.number
    });
}
```

However, this generates an error, presumably from Babel: `Parsing error: 'super' outside of function or class`.

This works, but is not very portable:

```
export default class ComponentTwo extends ComponentOne {
    static propTypes = Object.assign({
        baz: React.PropTypes.number
    }, ComponentOne.propTypes);
}
```

Are there any other ways to do this more cleanly/reusably?

Comment: Please be aware of the caveats when inheriting classes with static properties: 

"If you're inheriting from a class then static properties are inherited from it via `__proto__`, this is widely supported but you may run into problems with much older browsers.
NOTE: `__proto__` is not supported on IE <= 10 so static properties will not be inherited."

source: https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/caveats/

Comment: Have you tried doing the `super.propTypes` merge in the constructor?

Comment: @Mat I haven't, but given that `props` come into the constructor with defaults already set, I imagine that would be too late.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question, and it's been almost 3 years, but who know, someone might need it. (And it's still relevant)

Given that when you extend a class it automatically inherits of its parent class, you would not need to overwrite the `static propTypes` property.

Given a parent class:

```
class Parent {
  static propTypes = {
    parentProp: PropTypes.string
  }
}
```

If you don't want to add other propTypes/defaultProps, you can simply:

```
class Children extends Parent {
  // Do not declare the propTypes, it will extends by itself.
}
console.log(Children.propTypes); // Will output an object with parentProp in it
```

If you want to explicitly tell that you extends `Parent` propTypes, or add new propTypes:

```
class Children extends Parent {
  static propTypes = {
    ...Parent.propTypes, // Yes, you can spread static properties like everything else
    childProp: Proptypes.number,
  }
}
```

Small note, for this to work properly with Babel, you might need to include the `transform-es2015-classes` babel plugin in your plugins or preset. My `.babelrc`:

```
"presets": [
  ["env", {
    "include": ["transform-es2015-classes"]
  }],
  "stage-0",
  "react"
],
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Curiously enough, using `super` works for static methods. I'd think it should work for static properties too. To me, then, it feels more natural to use the super class name directly:

```
export default class ComponentTwo extends ComponentOne {
  static propTypes = _.merge({}, ComponentOne.propTypes, {
    baz: React.PropTypes.number
  });
}
```

But, to use `super`, one workaround I can think of is using a static method to initialize the property, which unfortunately would have to be called manually:

```
class ComponentTwo extends ComponentOne {
  static _init() { 
    this.propTypes = _.merge({}, super.propTypes, {
      baz: React.PropTypes.number
    });
  }
}
ComponentTwo._init();
```

Comment: Isn't this just a refactor of the suggestion at the end of my post? Using `lodash` instead of `Object.assign`? My problem with that is explicitly referencing `ComponentOne` instead of being able to refer to the "super" class. Not a big deal since you have to reference it in the `extends` statement, but not ideal.

Comment: Yes, that's precisely that, but with the right way of using _merge_.

Comment: Also added another alternative, which I think is worse.

Comment: U can probably get rid of the ini function by using a static get propTypes()